# Exception while calling another screen in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uistoryboard

I am new in IOS developing. In `Main.storyoard`, I added a new `viewcontroller`, assigned it to a new class `LoginViewController` and provided a storyboard-ID `loginview`. 
In the `LoginViewController` class, after successful login I tried the following code to call the default viewcontroller having storyboard-ID `webview`.

```
NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

During debugging I got the following exception

> 2016-05-04 18:37:11.020 gcmexample[2690:86862]
>   bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x7fa5d3f3d840: Tried to obtain the web
>   lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This
>   may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing
>   now... 1   0x11328d34b WebThreadLock 2   0x10e5547dd -[UIWebView
>   _webViewCommonInitWithWebView:scalesPageToFit:] 3   0x10e555179 -[UIWebView initWithCoder:] 4   0x10e7b5822 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue 5   0x10e7b5558 -[UINibDecoder
>   decodeObjectForKey:] 6   0x10e5e1483 -[UIRuntimeConnection
>   initWithCoder:] 7   0x10e7b5822 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue 8
>   0x10e7b59e3 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue 9   0x10e7b5558
>   -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] 10  0x10e5e06c3 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] 11  0x10e3b9eea -[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] 12  0x10e3ba816 -[UIViewController loadView] 13  0x10e3bab74 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] 14 
>   0x10e3bb2e7 -[UIViewController view] 15  0x10eb65f87
>   -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] 16  0x10e38af62 -[UIPresentationController
>   initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] 17 
>   0x10e3cdc8c -[UIViewController
>   _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] 18  0x10e3d0f2c -[UIViewController
>   _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] 19  0x10e3d0a3b -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] 20  0x10d065eed **34-[LoginViewController btnSign_in:]_block_invoke 21 
>   0x10fd3f6b5 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal
>   taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke 22 
>   0x10fd51a02 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask
>   _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke 23  0x10d1dc304 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** 24  0x10d118035 -[NSBlockOperation main] 25  0x10d0faf8a -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] 26  0x10d0fab9b __NSOQSchedule_f 27  0x11057f49b _dispatch_client_callout 28  0x1105658ec _dispatch_queue_drain 29  0x110564e0d _dispatch_queue_invoke 30  0x110567a56
>   _dispatch_root_queue_drain 31  0x1105674c5 _dispatch_worker_thread3

Does anyone know whats the error here? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code instead of your's. The problem seems to be you are doing an UI operation from different tread which you have created for login service. But it's recommended that the UI operation should performed on main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing present action on secondary thread instead `main thread`. All the UI Operations must be performed on Main Thread only, otherwise it will not take effect.

To perform some action on Main Thread use following `dispatch_async` block which performs on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyNetworkStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyNetworkTableViewController *myVC = (MyNetworkTableViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"networkController"];
UIViewController *frontViewController = myVC;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:frontViewController animated:YES];
```